Receiving an unknown error message trying to connect to PostgreSQL using .NET
Using PostgreSQL from a .NET application. Using the npgSQL Nuget package.
I can log on to the server using PGAdmin, but when I try it from .NET I get the following.
ERROR: XX000: DbHandler Exited
I validated all connection string parameters, and I can log into other PG database from .NET.
Only odd thing is that the Port is different (6543 rather than 5432)

Is port 6543 what you use in the pgAdmin connection?

Yes, proper port.   Turns out the issue is that when using Supabase, the default DB part of the connection string must be blank

The issue is that the connection string  when using Supabase, cannot have a value in the database field.   Once I cleared that out, I as able to connect
